# What does '(*b) (int) = fubar;' mean?

Tags: c

```
static void fubar(int a)
{
  void (*b) (int) = fubar; // <---
  static int c;
}
```

http://cdecl.org/ says syntax error.

My guess is that b is a pointer to a function returning int. Is this correct?

Comment: No, this is just a syntax error. There is no other meaning.

Comment: Don't be dishonest. The original snippet is shown [here](http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/Quiz4.sp12.pdf) (where it's not a syntax error).

Comment: @remyabel Still syntax error: http://tinyurl.com/lx24s4b

Comment: For cdecl to work, you need to remove the `= fubar` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My guess is that b is a pointer to a function returning int. Is this
>   correct?

You are close to the correct answer. It is indeed a pointer to a function that has return type `void` and one parameter of type `int`.

As you can see from the code snippet

```
static void fubar(int a)
{
  void (*b) (int) = fubar; // <---
  static int c;
}
```

in the right side of the assignment there is identifier `fubar` that is already declared like
`void fubar(int a)`. SO inside the function there is simply an assignment of it to a pointer of the same type.

Answer (score 3):

There has to be some return type,

```
void (*b) (int) = fubar;
```

or

```
int (*b) (int) = fubar;
```

Then it `b` would be, pointer to function which return `void`/`int` and takes `int` as parameter.

Answer (score 2):

there must be a return type to this as

int (*b) (int) = fubar;

so this explaines the b is the pointer to the function which take INT as parameter and it would return INT value